# Robotium : Test two different activity in one test case

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

I just got started with Robotium and tried to test the android phone and  contact  application in just one test case.

This is the scenario:

1- step

Start the phone application – Dial a number(33323589) – wait (3s) – finish the call- Go back to the phone app. Main screen – select the contacts list tab.

1. step( in the same test case)

Go to contacts list - Scroll down - select a contact and Dial the number.

The first step works  I am able to start the contact application, but not able to play with the contact list. 
My question is how to start the instrumentation of the contact application  when the phone application instrumentation was previously started.

I try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
intent.setClassName(getTargetContext(), "com.android.contacts.contactsList"); 
Activity activity = startActivitySync(intent);
```

has mention in this forum  http://groups.google.com/group/robotium-developers/browse_thread/thread/c82a02b4973cbb4d/7a6795ddbcd7c527?show_docid=7a6795ddbcd7c527

unfortunately its not working

please can you help me out of this problem ?

Thank you

Chindji

Answer (score 0):

You can not test two "Applications" at the same time with Robotium. I think in your case Contacts application is one app and Dialing a number is another one.
Better you can find the same at Robotium's project hosting site i.e. code.google.com
hAppyCoding